# When running knit to .Rmd output the chunks are not valid

Tags: r, knitr

#### Problem

When trying to `knit` an *.Rmd* containing `read_chunk` lines from `purl` scripts into a parent *.Rmd*, the chunks are not complete and only form code blocks. I want to be able to `knit` the output file normally.

#### Code

**main.Rmd**

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r, include=FALSE}
knitr::read_chunk("script_chunk.R")
```

### Print sessionInfo()

```{r, ref.label='script_chunk', eval=FALSE}
```
````

**script_chunk.R**

```
# ---- script_chunk
sessionInfo()
```

#### Knitting

When I process this with `knit("main.Rmd", "output.Rmd")` the following file is generated:

````
---
output: html_document
---



### Print sessionInfo()


```r
sessionInfo()
```
````

However, the desired output for the chunk is:

````
```{r script_chunk}
sessionInfo()
```
````

When I `knit` *output.Rmd* currently, I only get an un-evaluated code block because the chunk is missing the curly braces (and preferably the chunk name).

[image]

#### Workaround

I can use `readLines` to achieve what I'm after, for example with:

````
```{r, results='asis', collapse=TRUE, echo=FALSE}
cat("```{r script_chunk}\n")
cat(paste(readLines("script_chunk.R"), "\n", collapse = ""))
cat("```\n")
```
````

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Feels weird to knit an Rmd into another Rmd.

Comment: Are you sure you can do that? Is output.Rmd not just a markdown document with a wrong extension?

Comment: This is why I say this. Are you sure you don't produce a simple markdown document, which is why you would get an unexcecutable R chunk.

Comment: You can't just use `eval = TRUE` and print directly the result to HTML?

Comment: @F.Privé, no, the intermediate file will need to be regenerated without access to the original children

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a *slightly* more elegant solution:

````
# main.Rmd
---
output: html_document
---

### Print sessionInfo()

```{r, results="asis", echo = FALSE}
chunk_lines <- knitr::spin(text = readLines("script_chunk.R"), knit = FALSE)
cat(chunk_lines, sep = "\n")
```
````

But remember that your output, as far as `knitr` cares, is plain Markdown. `knitr` can only [output to certain formats](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/#package-options): LaTeX, Sweave, HTML, Markdown or Jekyll. While your output file has the `.Rmd` extension, its contents are plain Markdown because that's the default for R Markdown files.

So be aware that all code chunks you want in the output will have to be written as dynamic output. Which could leave you with obfuscated code in `main.Rmd`.

Comment: That is certainly an improvement! Do you have any thoughts on how you might implement that if you wanted to be able to `knit` either the final or intermediary document from `main.Rmd`?

Answer (score 3):

An alternative I use is with `knit_child`:

- `main.Rmd`

  ````
  ---
  output: html_document
  ---

  ```{r, include=FALSE}
  out <- knitr::knit_child("script_chunk.Rmd")
  ```

  ### Print sessionInfo()
  ```{r, ref.label='script_chunk'}
  paste(out, collapse = "\n")
  ```
  ````
- `script_chunk.Rmd`

  ````
  ```{r script_chunk}
  # ---- script_chunk
  sessionInfo()
  ```
  ````

When compiled:

````
---
output: html_document
---

### Print sessionInfo()

```r
# ---- script_chunk
sessionInfo()
```

```
## R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
## Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
## Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 16299)
## ... blah blah blah ...
```
````

Thoughts:

1. `out` is a horrible name for this;
2. I often use it to iterate a single child document (which handles one "thing") over zero or more things, so `out` can contain concatenated results of multiple calls to `knit_child`

Comment: Thank you for adding to the conversation. I'm still favouring Nathan's earlier approach because the child documents are `.R` scripts (from `purl`) and not R Markdown. Also, the output of the chunk is not desirable in `output.Rmd`, only the chunk contents.